# Как заполнить таблицу по диагонали в делфи?

Tags: delphi

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать приложение в делфи... Нужно заполнить таблицу SG числами по диагонали!

Comment: SG - это что такое? Мне это не понятно.

Comment: StringGrid

Comment: А по какой диагонали? Снизу вверх или наоборот?

Comment: Наоборот сверху вниз

Comment: То есть, по главной!?

Comment: Получается что да..

Comment: Могли бы и не жертвовать единственным очком репутации: это же такой простой пример! Говоря, что это простой пример, я не забываю о том, что первый программист - женщина!..

Comment: Так я ж студентка...и что то тяжко мне программирование даётся..а завтра ещё и экзамен..так что мне не жалко!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, как-то так:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i, j, n: Integer;
begin
  N:=StringGrid1.ColCount-1;
  Randomize;
  For i:=0 To n Do
    StringGrid1.Cells[i, i]:=IntToStr(Random(1000)-1000);
end;
```

Comment: Спасиб большое!Супер всё работает!!

Comment: А как заполнить снизу вверх???

Comment: Только проверочку бы, ColCount = RowCount

Comment: В общем-то, смысл заполнения по диагонали есть лишь тогда, когда ColCount = RowCount, думаю, что запихнуть это в условный оператор, и обработать условие, труда не составит.

Answer (score 0):

Снизу вверх :)

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
      i, n: Integer;
begin
  n:=StringGrid1.ColCount-1;
  Randomize;
  For i:=0 To n Do
     StringGrid1.Cells[n-i, i]:=IntToStr(Random(1000)-1000);
end;

end.
```